# Почему закрыли вопрос, тогда как он сосредоточен на одной проблеме?

Tags: обсуждение

Я задал следующий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409089/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC). Но его закрыли с замечанием:

> Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сосредоточен только на одной проблеме. Это поможет другим участникам дать ответ

В вопросе рассматривается одна конкретная проблема. У меня есть код и этот код нужно преобразовать определённым образом. В принципе, весь вопрос сосредоточен исключительно на этой проблеме. К тому же на него можно дать вполне конкретный ответ *(что я сам и сделал)*.

А ещё данный вопрос полезен для других людей, потому что в нём присутствуют ключевые фразы: `Имеется большое количество методов, которые надо переписать определённым образом`, `Какая технология позволит мне выполнить такое преобразование кода наиболее эффективно?` и `Какая технология может преобразовать текст данным образом?`, которые помогут вывести вопрос в поиске, когда кто-то другой столкнётся с похожей проблемой.

Похоже, что первый участник кинул тревогу по какой-то причине, а остальные не стали особо разбираться. Так или иначе, но я бы хотел услышать мнения тех людей, что закрыли мой вопрос - как по их мнению я должен его исправить.

Пожалуйста переоткройте мой вопрос. Он качественный и должен помогать людям.

Comment: На мой взгляд как человека, который голосовал за закрытие: вопрос про эффективность метода не может нести конкретики. Вы дали ответ, ответ хорош, не спорю, но мои познания в данной области стремятся к нулю и обоснования эффективности я не нашел. Я сагрился только на это. Вопрос на решение данной задачи или на поиск метода, не вызвал бы таких эмоций. Я за переоткрытие

Comment: @Dmitry ну вопрос не совсем про эффективность... Понятно, что тут на грани с "Вопросом основанным на мнениях", но всё-таки нужна конкретная технология. Потому что ну чистые реджексы не просто неэффективны, они тут практически бесполезны)